# Difficulties with connecting to WLAN with wpa_supplicant on a system rescue CD

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant, wlan, rescue

My box epicly failed and I am trying to get online to begin the rescue.
The very same config which used to work on my dead system doesn't work now  and I cannot connect to WLAN using the same parameters.
There are no significant errors other than `cannot connect to BSSID`.

This is my `wpa_supplicant.conf` file:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
update_config=1
network ={
    ssid="bssid1"
   psk="mypass"
    priority=1
}
network={
    ssid="bssid2"
    psk="my2nspass"
    priority=2
}
```

I start `wpa_supplicant` with

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlp2s0f0 -c /path/wpa_supplicant -D nl80211,wext
```

I tried using

```
nl80211,bsd
```

for the driver, same results.

I have 2 separate cards to try: `RealTek RTL8188CUS` and `Realtek RT3290` however both of them fail to connect in the same manner - they just cannot associate with bssid.

The only thing that has changed is the operating system.

My `wpa_supplicant` version is `v2.4`.

How do I connect to my WLAN with `wpa_supplicant` on a rescue CD?